# Can't run Core Java web application into Azure Web app

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have written a core java web application using maven-archetype-webapp and trying to deploy the jar file and web.config in a azure windows based webapp but not able to access the url. I only have home page inside my application. and following below steps. I am able to run it in my local system and can see the homepage.

1. azure-webapp-maven-plugin added in POM and build with mvn azure-webapp:config, then inside configuration tag I added below tag.

```
<appSettings>
    <property>
        <name>JAVA_OPTS</name>
        <value>-Dserver.port=80</value>
    </property>
</appSettings>
```

2. Created a web app in Windowsusing Java 8 and Tomcat 8.5
3. Deployed jar file and web.config file inside wwwroot directory

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
                      arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\TestWebApp.jar&quot;">
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Folder Structure

[image]

Azure directory structure

[image]

Local system Output:

[image]

Comment: I am not quite sure what is your problem?

Comment: When I am clicking on the azure web app url I am getting response saying Service unavailable. In my local system I am able to run the application in tomcat and can see the home page.

Comment: Are you using spring?

Comment: No, this is a core java application.

Comment: In web app did you choose java?

Comment: Yes, I have chosen Java 8, Tomcat 8.5

Comment: Try to replace   processPath="%ProgramW6432%\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe"

Comment: Same result, Service Unavailable, 503 HTTP error

Comment: Found the solution, deployed the war file inside wwwroot -> webapps folder in azure webapp. Before deploying deleted the Root folder inside webapps, after my deployment new root folder was automatically generated, now I can access the url.

Comment: Hi, I have update the solution of this question in the answer. Can you mark it as the answer to end this question? That may help others who meet the similar question. You can also post your own answer and mark it to end this question. If so, let me know and I will delete my answer.:)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @soumen for the solution.

> Deployed the `war` file inside `wwwroot` -> `webapps` folder in azure
> webapp. Before deploying deleted the `Root` folder inside `webapps`, after
> my deployment new root folder was automatically generated, now I can
> access the url.

I take it as an answer, hoping to help other members.